# Why can the environment variable TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES be set with multi values?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

The environment variable TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES can be set as:
TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES=3.0,3.5,5.2,7.0,7.5, why can it be set with multi values?

Answer (score 4):

TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES is a build time parameter for TensorFlow, it has no effect if you set it at runtime.

Setting it to multiple values allows you to build a TensorFlow install image that supports multiple types of GPUs with the cuda libraries to leverage the abilities of the graphic card's hardware.

The more TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES values you include, the longer the build will take and the larger the final wheel size will be.

Using this web page: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#compute, you can find the cuda compute capabilities value for each graphic card you wish to use. If your using a P100 for example the compute capability would be 6.0.

Continuing the example if you built TensorFlow with only compute capability 6.0, and then installed in on a system with a V100 (compute capability 7.0), it would work, but it would not run as fast as if it was built including compute capability 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

To fit different CUDA verisons while compiling, I suppose.